# Nvidia Visual profiler Error: Cannot create profiling file

Tags: cuda, profiling, openacc, pgi, nvprof

I'm a new user of nvprof and I got an error when I tried to use nvprof to profile my code. I added some OpenACC directives to my code. The cuda toolkit I used is Cuda8.0. My code is written in fortran90+OpenMPI. I used 16 cores for parallel computing. Here is the script I used to submit the code:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=16
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=24
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-core=2
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --constraint=gpu
#SBATCH --time=24:00:00
#SBATCH --account=s807

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK
export CRAY_CUDA_MPS=1
export TMPDIR=/scratch/snx3000/guow/Incompact3d_GPU/test1
export PGI_ACC_TIME=1

set -ex

# set some parameters
OUT=log.txt
#WMIN=1400
NP=16


# tasks: $SLURM_NTASKS 
# tasks-per-node: $SLURM_NTASKS_PER_NODE 
# cpus-per-task: $SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK
srun nvprof -o nvprof.out ./incompact3d $WMIN >> $OUT
```

The job is terminated after running for several seconds and I got the error message below:

```
+ OUT=log.txt
+ NP=16
+ srun nvprof -o nvprof.out ./incompact3d
==20144== NVPROF is profiling process 20144, command: ./incompact3d
==20148== NVPROF is profiling process 20148, command: ./incompact3d
==20140== NVPROF is profiling process 20140, command: ./incompact3d
==20133== NVPROF is profiling process 20133, command: ./incompact3d
==20134== NVPROF is profiling process 20134, command: ./incompact3d
==20150== NVPROF is profiling process 20150, command: ./incompact3d
==20146== NVPROF is profiling process 20146, command: ./incompact3d
==20128== NVPROF is profiling process 20128, command: ./incompact3d
==20154== NVPROF is profiling process 20154, command: ./incompact3d
==20156== NVPROF is profiling process 20156, command: ./incompact3d
==20152== NVPROF is profiling process 20152, command: ./incompact3d
==20136== NVPROF is profiling process 20136, command: ./incompact3d
==20130== NVPROF is profiling process 20130, command: ./incompact3d
==20158== NVPROF is profiling process 20158, command: ./incompact3d
==20138== NVPROF is profiling process 20138, command: ./incompact3d
==20142== NVPROF is profiling process 20142, command: ./incompact3d
==20146== Error: Cannot create profiling file: /scratch/snx3000/guow/Incompact3d_GPU/test2_OpenAcc/nvprof.out
==20142== Error: Cannot create profiling file: /scratch/snx3000/guow/Incompact3d_GPU/test2_OpenAcc/nvprof.out
==20138== Error: Cannot create profiling file: /scratch/snx3000/guow/Incompact3d_GPU/test2_OpenAcc/nvprof.out
==20133== Error: Cannot create profiling file: /scratch/snx3000/guow/Incompact3d_GPU/test2_OpenAcc/nvprof.out
==20134== Error: Cannot create profiling file: /scratch/snx3000/guow/Incompact3d_GPU/test2_OpenAcc/nvprof.out
==20136== Error: Cannot create profiling file: /scratch/snx3000/guow/Incompact3d_GPU/test2_OpenAcc/nvprof.out
==20156== Error: Cannot create profiling file: /scratch/snx3000/guow/Incompact3d_GPU/test2_OpenAcc/nvprof.out
srun: First task exited 30s ago
srun: tasks 0,4,6-7,9-13: running
srun: tasks 1-3,5,8,14-15: exited
srun: Terminating job step 3892463.0
slurmstepd: error: *** STEP 3892463.0 ON nid04439 CANCELLED AT 2017-10-12T15:04:00 ***
srun: Job step aborted: Waiting up to 32 seconds for job step to finish.
srun: error: nid04439: tasks 0,4,6-7,9-13: Killed
srun: Terminating job step 3892463.0
```

A nvprof.out file is generated but nothing is shown when I use the command "nvvp nvprof.out" to check it. Have you ever met this kind of situation before? Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the command:

```
srun nvprof -o nvprof.%p.out ./incompact3d $WMIN >> $OUT
```

"%p" will get filled in with the process ID for each MPI Rank so each rank will output it's profile to different files.  Otherwise, all the ranks are trying to use the same file which can cause problems.

Comment: Hi Mat, thanks for your reply. It works when I add %p. It can generate 16 output files. But when I import those 16 output files to nvprof, nothing is shown in the GPU details, CPU details label. And I can only see the timeline row of OpenACC. In the Analysis label when I click "Examine GPU Usage", the results show "No GPU Devices". But the code is run on CPU and GPU. Could you tell me how to display the GPU,CPU details and other timeline information?

Comment: If you're code runs on the GPU, then there should be GPU information.  Though, if the nodes don't have "libcupti.so" installed, that could explain why the information is missing.  CUPTI is the profiler library that interfaces with the device.  Another possibility is that you didn't build the OpenACC code for the device you're using.  What "-ta" options did you pass to the compiler?  What device are you using?    For CPU profiling, you need to add the "--cpu-profiling on" option to nvprof, or use pgprof which enables CPU profiling by default.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The -ta option I used is -ta=tesla:cuda8.0. I'm running my simulation on Cray XC50. The compute node is Intel® Xeon® E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz (12 cores, 64GB RAM) and NVIDIA® Tesla® P100 16GB. I added "--cpu-profilling on" option and I used a single core to compute. Now I can see the CPU profiling.

Comment: "-ta=tesla:cuda8.0" will include P100 as one of the default target devices, so you're good there.  Can you add "-Minfo=accel" and review the compiler feedback messages to see if the compiler is generating device kernels?  Also, try setting the environment variable "PGI_ACC_TIME=1" and then run without nvprof.  This should produce a simple GPU profile.  If you only see "elapsed time", which is measured from the host, but no "device_time" which is measured via libcupti, then we'll know that it's a libcupti issue.

Comment: Hi Mat. I add -Minfo=accel and I can see the feedback from compiler saying "Accelerator kernel generated". When I set PGI_ACC_TIME=1, I can see the "elapsed time" but I cannot see the "device_time" after the statement saying "kernel launched xxxx times". But the device time is  shown after the statement "data copyin transfers: xxxxxx" and "data copyout transfers: xxxxxx". Maybe as you said it is a libcupti issue.

Comment: My guess is if you look at the beginning of your output, you'll see a warning from the PGI runtime that libcupti couldn't be loaded since this is the output I'd expect is it wasn't loaded.  If either PGI or the CUDA SDK are installed on the local nodes, then you might be able to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to it's location.  I'd talk with your local admin to see if it's available and if not, have them install it for you.